# How to change assembly directory ? VS Couldn't find assembly in the folder

Tags: macos, visual-studio, mono, post-build-event

I'm trying to create a program for a Thermal Printer.

I download a Hello World example from Intermec Website.

But when i try to run it say :

> /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.20.1/lib/mono/msbuild/15.0/bin/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(5,5):
>   Error MSB3073: Command "mono
>   c:/Intermec/SmartPrintingRK/Utils/FtpPut.exe HelloWorld.exe
>   ftp://10.203.33.124/apps/HelloWorld.exe user pass" stop with code 2.
>   (MSB3073) (HelloWorld)

I try to remove and add again assembly but without any success.

> PostBuildEvent cible :
>       mono c:/Intermec/SmartPrintingRK/Utils/FtpPut.exe HelloWorld.exe ftp://10.203.33.124/apps/HelloWorld.exe user pass
>       Cannot open assembly 'c:/Intermec/SmartPrintingRK/Utils/FtpPut.exe': No such file or
>   directory.
>       /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.20.1/lib/mono/msbuild/15.0/bin/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(5167,5):
>   error MSB3073: Command "mono
>   c:/Intermec/SmartPrintingRK/Utils/FtpPut.exe HelloWorld.exe
>   ftp://10.203.33.124/apps/HelloWorld.exe user pass" stop with code 2.
>   Génération de la cible "PostBuildEvent" end in
>   project"HelloWorld.csproj" -- FAILED
>
> 'c:/Intermec/SmartPrintingRK/Utils/FtpPut.exe': No such file or
>   directory.'

But i'm on a mac so sure you couldn't find file ... 
How to change it ?

Answer (score 1):

Okay find a way to fix it. 
Right click on your project name in the tree, 
then select 'Tools' then edit file. 
At the end of the script, the directory name should be changed by the actual directory of FtpPut.exe